Class '...TCPNetSyslogConfig' contains multiple setters for the same property 'facility'
I have logback configuration like this:
<configuration>


    <appender name="SYSLOG-DEFAULT-APPENDER" class="com.papertrailapp.logback.Syslog4jAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>IRC: %m%n%xEx</pattern>
        </layout>

        <syslogConfig class="org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.net.tcp.TCPNetSyslogConfig">
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>
            <port>514</port>
            <ident>guacamole_client</ident>
            <facility>local0</facility>
            <maxMessageLength>128000</maxMessageLength>
        </syslogConfig>
    </appender>

   
    <!-- Log at INFO level -->
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG-DEFAULT-APPENDER" />
    </root>

</configuration>

But when I start application sometimes(!) I see the error with stacktrace:
11:10:40,478 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
11:10:40,564 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - Processing appender named [SYSLOG-DEFAULT-APPENDER]
11:10:40,564 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler - About to instantiate appender of type [com.papertrailapp.logback.Syslog4jAppender]
11:10:40,586 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.beans.BeanDescriptionFactory@1c5d2f51 - Class 'org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.net.tcp.TCPNetSyslogConfig' contains multiple setters for the same property 'delimiterSequence'.
11:10:40,586 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.beans.BeanDescriptionFactory@1c5d2f51 - Class 'org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.net.tcp.TCPNetSyslogConfig' contains multiple setters for the same property 'facility'.
11:10:40,586 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.beans.BeanDescriptionFactory@1c5d2f51 - Class 'org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.net.tcp.TCPNetSyslogConfig' contains multiple setters for the same property 'splitMessageEndText'.
11:10:40,586 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.beans.BeanDescriptionFactory@1c5d2f51 - Class 'org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.net.tcp.TCPNetSyslogConfig' contains multiple setters for the same property 'splitMessageBeginText'.
11:10:40,587 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@6a7d70b0 - Failed to set property [facility] to value "local0".  ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetterException: Conversion to type [int] failed. 
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.PropertySetterException: Conversion to type [int] failed. 
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter.setProperty(PropertySetter.java:119)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter.setProperty(PropertySetter.java:96)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler.doBasicProperty(ImplicitModelHandler.java:111)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler.handle(ImplicitModelHandler.java:86)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:241)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:208)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:170)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configureByResource(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:68)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:35)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.invokeConfigure(ContextInitializer.java:128)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:103)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:66)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initializeLoggerContext(LogbackServiceProvider.java:52)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initialize(LogbackServiceProvider.java:41)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:196)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:183)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:486)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:472)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.addStatus(StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.java:34)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.addInfo(StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.java:22)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(LogbackServletContainerInitializer.java:33)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4438)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:599)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:571)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:603)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1751)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at  at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:264)
    at  at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at  at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:453)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:407)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at  at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:264)
    at  at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at  at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at  at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
    at  at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
    at  at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
    at  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at  at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
    at  at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at  at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at  at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at  at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at  at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at  at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at  at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at  at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at  at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "local0"
    at  at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:999)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.StringToObjectConverter.convertArg(StringToObjectConverter.java:62)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter.setProperty(PropertySetter.java:117)
    at  ... 72 common frames omitted

logback version is 1.5.6
I see that reason that AbstractSyslogConfig has 2 setters for facility:
11:10:40,586 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.beans.BeanDescriptionFactory@1c5d2f51 - Class 'org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.net.tcp.TCPNetSyslogConfig' contains multiple setters for the same property 'facility'

code is:
public void setFacility(int facility) {
    this.facility = facility;
}

public void setFacility(String facilityName) {
    this.facility = SyslogUtility.getFacility(facilityName);
}

Is there workaround how to fix it ?
P.S.
I also created issue on github but no feedback at all

Not sure if it is the best option but I've found the solution:

Extend the TCPNetSyslogConfig

    public class MyCustomTcpNetSyslogConfig extends TCPNetSyslogConfig {
        public void setMyFacility(String facility) {
            setFacility(facility);
        }
    }


use it in logback.xml:

<appender name="SYSLOG-DEFAULT-APPENDER" class="com.papertrailapp.logback.Syslog4jAppender">
    ...
    <syslogConfig class="org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.net.tcp.MyCustomTcpNetSyslogConfig ">
        ...
        <myFacility>local0</myFacility>
        ...
    </syslogConfig>
</appender>

....

